# Admob Money receive

Tags: android, paypal

I had created an android [game Burgers](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.younque.burgers) .. N i had linked admob advertisements in it , now i have earned around 6$ i know that's not pretty much , but still as a beginner i would like accept it :P . . Now how am i gonna receive that money ? Like how am i gonna link my credit card to admob so that they can transfer money into my account ? And also is admob linked to my playstore developer account ? because i don't want to receive money via credit card which is linked to my playstore account.Btw i have no idea what paypal is :P .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admob pay the amount over $100, and only a month later, when you earned it.
In addition, first you have to earn $15 and verify your address.
Explore the [help section](https://support.google.com/admob/topic/2745447?hl=en&ref_topic=2792286&vid=1-635779924334838906-2727347094). There are answers to all questions.
(besides, they're kind of canceled payments PayPal)

But in general, your question does not explicitly address.

Comment: Thank You :) so first now i have to earn $15 to verify my address . Right ?

Comment: Yes. You'll be sent postcard (with a code) to the offline address.